# Eevee - How to use the Shadow Catcher in blender 3.0?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

How to do Shadow Catcher in blender 3.0. In 2.9 is very easy to make  Shadow Catcher. But I can't find it in 3.0

[image]

I don't have shadow catcher?!

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Shadow_Catcher gives the overview.  https://youtu.be/w70dMniat2M is a good tutorial

Comment: But I want to use eevee. So how to render a shadow catcher in EEVEE?

Comment: EEVEE doesn't use the Shadow Catcher, it's a Cycle's (X) Feature.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=shadow+catcher+eevee

Comment: Try this plugin instead https://youtu.be/CbUzPHQK00I

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame nobody answered your question. My problem I found was using an older mac. I had the same problem and stumbled on this forum. I found the reason Shadow Catcher was not showing up in my 3.2.2 version of Blender was because on my older mac, the CPU's did not support that feature. How I found that out was by going to the top menu of "edit", then down to "Preferences". In preferences went down to "System". At the top of system under Cycle Render Devices is 'None' or 'Metal' When I clicked 'Metal', it said, "No compatible GPUs found for Cycles. Requires Apple Silicon with macOS 12.2 or newer or ADM with macOS 12.3 or newer. My mac is still running High Sierra 10.13.6. Hope that helps.