# Shadow Catcher option missing (3.0)

Tags: rendering, objects

[image]

I searched so much videos to solve this issue and there's no answers. every video says that the shadow catcher option is at Object Properties > Visibility > Mask. i follow those steps to find that the option is not there anymore. last time i used blender for the shadow catcher (a few months ago), the option was there, now, its just gone. I'm using 3.0 if that ever helps.

Edit: I am dumb, I have forgotten to change the render engine to cycles

Comment: Honestly, I think it might be worthwhile if you write that it's only available in Cycles as an answer, along with a little bit of information about how and where to change to Cycles.  You're certainly not the only person to have had this problem (I remember doing it myself at least once!) and while I suspect there might well be a duplicate somewhere, if you add an self-accept an answer, anyone else coming to this question with the same problem will find the solution where they expect it.

Comment: @Ben for example this thread also without an answer :)) https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252052/78972

Answer (score 1):

[image: Render Engine Menu to change to Cycles]It's a shame nobody answered your question. Yesterday I thought my problem was using an older mac. I thought I'd found the reason "Shadow Catcher" was not showing up in my 3.2.2 version of Blender was because on my older mac, the CPU's did not support that feature. I this was because I went into the "Preferences" menu. In preferences went down to "System" and at the top of "System" under Cycle Render Devices is 'None' or 'Metal'.  When I clicked 'Metal', it said, "No compatible GPUs found for Cycles. Requires Apple Silicon with macOS 12.2 or newer or ADM with macOS 12.3 or newer.  My mac is still running High Sierra 10.13.6.  But today, I changed that preferences settings to allow for memory limit from "0" to "300". Not sure if that helped? But more importantly - I found where you change the RENDER ENGINE SETTINGS. (see attached) After changing the setting on the drop down menu to "Cycles" the "Shadow Catcher" became available. What's confusing is you have to go to a different menu to find shadow catcher.  After the render engine menu, click on the light source, then down on "Visibility" and there you'll see and can check off the box for "Shadow Catcher". [Render Engine Drop Down Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO125.png) Change from default EEVEE to Cycles. Cheers!

[3}[Click on Light menu - then Visibility and see Shadow Catcher]