# Shadow Catcher missing in 3.2

Tags: shadowcatcher

I was trying to capture shadows on transparency and was following a Youtube video, and the very first step I could not do.

The video said to select the object to receive the shadow and go to the *Object Properties* panel under the *Visibility* sub-panel and check *On* under the Mask heading "Shadow Catcher".

That option does not even exist.  It shows *Holdout* as the only option to check.  Also, every other location the video says to check *Shadow Catcher*, that option doesn't exist anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?  Blender 3.2 on iMac.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Comment: You need to set the render engine to *Cycles* to see the Shadow Catcher checkbox. *Eevee* does not have this setting.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the link seems not to be correct. It leads to this question.

Comment: @Blunder Indeed, my mistake. Meant to link to this one instead https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264135/shadow-catcher-option-missing-3-0

Comment: Are you on Cycles or eevee?, if you're on eevee change to cycles